# PHP fopen() inside javascript logic bug

Tags: javascript, php, html, debugging, fopen

I want to create a text file stole to localhost directory.
below is my code.

below app.php

````
            document.getElementById("save_button").addEventListener("click", function() {
          
              var content =  document.getElementById("final_span").value();

              var file_name =document.getElementById("filename").value();
              <?php
              $fn = strstr($file_name,'.', true);

              $dir = "../project/Record";

              $file = fopen($dir."/".$fn.".txt","w+");

              fwrite($file, $content);

              fclose($file);
              ?>
            });
      </script>```
````

Comment: You make some misunderstanding with server side code and client side code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your js will execute in browser and php is server side language. You can't control php within js as you've done. You can do it by ajax call from you js to php file and create a file.

```
    <script>  document.getElementById("save_button").addEventListener("click", function() {
              
                  var content =  document.getElementById("final_span").value;
    
                  var file_name =document.getElementById("filename").value;
    
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
          }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "app.php?file_name=" + file_name, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    
    </script>
```

app.php

```
<?php $file_name= $_GET['file_name'];
              $fn = strstr($file_name,'.', true);

              $dir = "../project/Record";

              $file = fopen($dir."/".$fn.".txt","w+");

              fwrite($file, $content);

              fclose($file);
              ?>
```

Comment: why no respond on app.php ?
this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200    it is true

Comment: you can echo any response you want but it seems you didn't set any response message.

Comment: Okay solve thank you. if i also want to pass the var content =  document.getElementById("final_span").value(); also ?

Comment: Pls replace with below line

"app.php?file_name=" + file_name +"&content="+content

Comment: can hide the content ? not send with this method?

Comment: You can send them in post method. pls refer this post for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30414372/ajax-post-implementation-in-pure-javascript